# Why is the GUI text in my Vagrant VirtualBox VM jumping around?

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine

I’m running a Vagrant Ubuntu desktop through VirtualBox VM on a 2014 MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite, 10.10.4 (the contents of which I migrated *in toto* from an older MacBook Pro earlier this year). I had run the same configuration without any problems on the older machine, but now Ubuntu’s GUI text bounces around so much so that it’s hard to even click on anything to try and explore what’s going on.

What *is* going on?[image: Jumping GUI text]

Comment: Can you copy your Vagrantfile to another directory and fire `vagrant up` inside it to test if the problem persists?

Comment: But this question remains “unanswered” (and [Meta’s proposed remedy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) for that doesn’t make sense).

Comment: Well, this is not an anwer. It was just a try to diagnose your problem. Seems something happened to the VM image you've migrated your old macbook. I do not know what happened and how to fix it